# Recompose : Equivalant of the combination withState/withHandlers with withStateHandlers

Tags: recompose

Simple question: if i want to use withStateHandlers instead of the couple withState/withHandlers. What is the equivalant of this :

```
withState('value', 'updateValue', ''),
withHandlers({
    onChange: ({updateValue}) => event => updateValue(event.target.value)
})
```

Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

`withStateHandlers` doesn't have named `stateUpdater` (like `updateValue` in your case), so you need to interact with the state directly.

```
withStateHandlers(
  // you define the initial state
  { value: '' }, 
  // this is handler - you return a new state - updated value in this case
  { onChange: () => event => ({ value: event.target.value }) } 
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know why i have this error :
`warning.js:35 Warning: performUpdateIfNecessary: Unexpected batch number (current 70, pending 69)` ?

Comment: For now, i just use the combination of withState/withHandlers and it's works.